# Time string in influxdb query not returning any data

Tags: influxdb

```
SELECT "value" FROM "gt_01_ai_xxlc32091" where time >= 1466634590000
```

Results

```
time        value
----        -----
1466634590000   0.550742865
1466634595000   0.554207444
1466634600000   0.564015567
```

The equivalent for 1466634590000 is Date RFC 3339   2016-06-22T18:29:50-04:00

However the below query does not provide any results. Can you help?

```
SELECT "value" FROM "gt_01_ai_xxlc32091" where time >= '2016-06-22 18:29:50'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Really need help. Here is a data point I inserted `gt_01_ai_xxlc32091,productname=validation,campaignname=d1600034-00,recipename=d1600050-01,recipeversion=3 value=-0.00101705 1464112015`  the 1464112015 is clearly 5/24/2016. However when I select the same data in influx db it says its timestamp is 01/01/1970. Please help how can I fix this.

Comment: `SELECT "value" FROM "gt_01_ai_xxlc32091" where "value"=-0.00101705`
Output from influx db
`time    value
----    -----
1970-01-01T00:00:01.464112015Z  -0.00101705`

Answer (score 0):

By default InfluxDB expects timestamps to be specified with nanosecond level precision and it appears that you've specified your timestamp with second level precision.

You can specify timestamp precision by adding `precision=s` as a query parameter to the `/write` endpoint of the HTTP API.

See the [`/write`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/tools/api/#write) endpoint documentation for more information.